# How to inject jQuery and window/document to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dependency-injection

I created an object that uses jQuery to attach events to and to manipulate DOM. Of course, the jQuery and the DOM it can manipulate is already available anywhere inside the object:

```
    var editor = new Editor();
    editor.init();

    function Editor()
    {
        this.init(){
            this.attachEventHandlers();
        };

        this.attachEventHandlers(){
            $('#someElement').on('click', this.someElementClicked);
        };

        this.someElementClicked= function(e){
            //do something
        };
    }
```

as you can see in the attachEventHandlers, jQuery is already available and it knows what DOM tree to use.

**I wonder if I can inject the window/document and jQuery when initializing the object instead of them being available right away.**

I'm not sure if what I'm doing will do me any good, I'm just tinkering things. It just feel so wrong now to access the DOM and use jQuery without them being injected to the object.

I'm aware Angular have solved this issue (dependency) but I wonder how can I make my scripts organized with only jQuery/plain JavaScript.

Comment: Where and when are you using `editor` object?

Comment: @Satpal any page. Thanks for the question, I got an idea.